# ASP.Net MVC Api won't accept an int parameter

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, converters

I have the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ReturnStatus> Delete([FromBody]int id)
{
    await new BusinessLogic.Templates().DeleteTemplate(id);

    return ReturnStatus.ReturnStatusSuccess();
}
```

When I run this as an AJAX request, the id is null.  I've inspected the data coming in through Fiddler and the body is:

```
{"id":"11"}
```

The header has Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8.

If I modify the code slightly to

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ReturnStatus> Delete([FromBody]string id)
{
    await new BusinessLogic.Templates().DeleteTemplate(Convert.ToInt64(id));

    return ReturnStatus.ReturnStatusSuccess();
}
```

it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Should that not be `{"id":11}` for an int param?

Comment: I changed the ajax call to send {"id":11} and it still does the same thing.  :(

Comment: Have you done anything to your routing configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this part, number 3 in particular: 
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/
3. [FromBody] parameters must be encoded as =value
(quoting the section for future reference:)

There are two ways to make jQuery satisfy Web API’s encoding requirement. First, you can hard code the = in front of your value, like this:

```
$.post('api/values', "=" + value);
```

Personally, I’m not a fan of that approach. Aside from just plain looking kludgy, playing fast and loose with JavaScript’s type coercsion is a good way to find yourself debugging a “wat” situation.
Instead, you can take advantage of how jQuery encodes object parameters to `$.ajax`, by using this syntax:

```
$.post('api/values', { '': value });
```